# Loading Images into native UIImagePickerController allowsEditing

Tags: ios, swift, uiimagepickercontroller

I am trying to do the following:

I've got images, that I get from Facebook directly. Since they are not formatted in the right ratio (square). I want the user to crop it themselves right after getting them.

My Idea: Adding the image to the allowsEditing View from the native UIImagePickerController.

Is this possible?

Comment: You need to do cropping manually...using core graphics framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to open native crop. You can only open `UIImagePickerController`, with `allowsEditing = YES` and select imaged from local library.

You can use this library to solve your problem:
https://github.com/TimOliver/TOCropViewController